# Bigquery Redshift migration of 2 TB+ size table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to migrate Redshift to BigQuery . The table size is 2TB+
I am using bigquery redshift data transfer service.
But the migration is running for more than 5 hours.

Also also see that the queries that gets executed at the Redshift end unloads data into 50 MB chunks. As there there is no way to configure chunk size parameter in Redshift transfer job.

It this much time to transfer 2TB of data from redshfit to BigQuery is expected or something can be done to improve this job.

There are some system like snowflake in just 2-3 hours from Redshift to their end.

Answer (score 2):

Bigquery redshift data transfer service is built on top of the Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service. The end to end data movement involves:
1. Extract data from Redshift cluster to S3
2. Move data from S3 to GCS
3. Load data from GCS into BQ

While the 2nd and 3rd steps are quick, the first step is actually limited by the Redshift cluster itself, since it's the Redshift Cluster which executes the UNLOAD command.

Some options to make this faster can be:
1. Upgrade to a powerful cluster.
2. Do Redshift workload management (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_workload_mngmt_classification.html) to give Migration Account (The one provided to Bigquery redshift data transfer service) better priority and resources to run the UNLOAD command.

Comment: Actually I suggest you directly reach out to bq-dts-support@google.com to get official help. My team is working on Bigquery redshift data transfer service, and I believe you'll get sufficient support.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with the redshift data transfer service, but I have used the Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service (available [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/transfer)) and in my experience it's very scalable.  It should transfer 2TB of data in under an hour.  If you've got millions of smallish files to transfer it might take a couple hours but it should still work.

Once you've got the data in google cloud storage you can either import it into BigQuery or create a federated table that scans over the data in google cloud storage.

Comment: But I believe BigQuery data transfer service does not stage data into a GCS bucket. It directly loads data from S3 to bigquery. this is because this service does not asks me to specify any gcs bucket nor does it create any staging bucket. Update: the data unload query is still running

Comment: Just to clarify a point in case it's causing confusion: My answer doesn't suggest using the 'BigQuery Data Transfer Service' -- instead it suggests using the 'Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service'.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, instead of using s3->gcs->BQ, why not s3->BQ ?

Comment: Maybe the S3->BQ route would work quickly too, and if so that could be a simpler approach for you--I have no experience with that route to so don't know if it's fast or slow.  I suggested the s3->gcs->bq route because I know that route is quick from my own experience.